# Excel 2013: Acquiring the directory of a .xltm template file in one of its instances

Tags: excel, vba, templates, instance

I'm writing (VBA) a .xltm file in Excel 2013. The user of this file will create an instance of it, and should be able to save a copy of this instance in a repository predetermined by myself.

For this I use

```
RepoPath = WORKDIR & "\SETUP_REPOSITORY\" & ProjectName
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs RepoPath & "\" & NewFileName
```

in which the WORKDIR is the directory containing the template. This folder is located on a shared drive, and I get its value through a subroutine:

```
Sub SetDefaults() 
    WORKDIR = ActiveWorkbook.Path
End Sub
```

This one is called upon opening the workbook in the Workbook_Open() subroutine in the ThisWorkbook object.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Module1.SetDefaults
End Sub
```

Now, this works fine when I'm trying to save a copy of the file from the template, but when I create a new instance of the template ("template1"), the WORKDIR variable is not properly initialized, and I do not get pointed to the correct folder anymore.

So I was wondering if there is any other way of passing the path to the excel template to instances of it?

I can not simply use an absolute path since it's on a shared drive, and I'm kind of lost for ideas right now (though I'll gladly admit I'm pretty new to VBA).

Any help and suggestions is very welcome!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, a copy derived from a template *always* has an empty string as its path property, because it is an unsaved copy of a file. One way around this is to stop using the template filetype, but use a "normal" Excel file which you set to read-only. Then your file opening code can somehow detect whether or not this is the "original" file being opened and if so, read the path and do the save-as.

Comment: Aah, thanks for the reply, that makes sense.
I'm afraid though that the workaround is impossible for me. The user needs to enter some data before saving the file, so read-only will not work.
Maybe it's a stretch, but do you know any other way around?

Comment: If you set the file to read-only through it's Windows properties, all you are preventing is the user from saving the file using the same name and location. They can still save-as to anywhere else or use another file name.